# How can I parse xmlrpc response (Odoo API read), using Java

Tags: api, parsing, response, odoo, xml-rpc

I have to fetch the category a product is related to, using the read method of Odoo API. I get a list of objects, then for each category, I need to extract the field product_tmpl_ids, a list of integers. I'm not sure how to do it. This is the method:

```
public List readModelfields(String modelName, List<Integer> ids, List<String> fields, Integer uid) throws XmlRpcException {
    List record = (List) Arrays.asList((Object[]) models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
            db, uid, password,
            modelName, "read",
            ids,
            new HashMap() {{
                put("fields", fields);
            }}
    )));
    return record;
}
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add("product_tmpl_ids");
List categoryIds = (List<Integer>)service.searchByStrParameter("product.public.category", "name", "A - Administration / Office", uid);
List result = (List)service.readModelfields("product.public.category", categoryIds, fields, uid);
```

Can anybody help? How to extract the fields from the fetched objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the result of the search method (a list) to `readModelfields` which is used as-is to call `read` method, as documented in External API [read](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#read-records) method `ids` must be passed in a list:

```
Arrays.asList(ids),
```

You used search followed with the read method on the same model, you can use [search_read](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html#search-and-read) instead.

The following example shows how to fetch the many2many field `category_id` of `res.partners`

```
public List searchReadModelfields(String modelName, List domain, List<String> fields, Integer uid) throws XmlRpcException {
    return (List)Arrays.asList((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
            db, uid, password,
            modelName,
            "search_read",
            Arrays.asList(domain),
            new HashMap() {{
                put("fields", fields);
            }}
    )));
}
```

Call `searchReadModelfields` and print out the values:

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add("category_id");
List domain = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("category_id", "!=", false)
);

// return list of hashmaps)
List result = (List)service.searchReadModelfields("res.partner", domain, fields, uid);

HashMap values;
Integer partner_id;
Object[] category_ids;
for(Object partner_data: result) {
    values  = (HashMap)partner_data;
    partner_id = (Integer) values.get("id");
    category_ids = (Object [])values.get("category_id");

    System.out.printf("{partner_id: %s, ", partner_id);
    System.out.print("category_ids:[");
    for(Object category_id: category_ids) {
        System.out.printf("%s,",
                category_id
        );
    }
    System.out.println("]}");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kenly! Clear and to the point as usual. I applied the solution and it worked.